# Trouble with Android Listview Selector

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView`, each row of the list has has `TextView` and `ImageView`. I am using a selector for `ImageView` and I want when I click only on that `ImageView` of row, it will change but my when I click anywhere else on the row the `ImageView` become unaffected.

**Selector code**

```
<selector xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/download_h"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/download"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: So you want when you click anywhere on a row except ImageView, you want your ImageView to go back to default?

Comment: No I want when I click on ImageView it will change for a moment and resume back to its preview image and if I press anywhere else on that row then there should be no action

Comment: Lemme see your selector implementation code?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/download_h"
          android:state_pressed="true"           
          />    
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/download" />        
</selector>

Comment: Always put your code in the question

Comment: How did you set it to your ImageView? src? or background?

Comment: android:src="@drawable/selectorxml"

Comment: How about changing it to android:background="@drawable/selectorxml"

Comment: Wow! We need to see the relevant codes I guess.

Answer (score 0):

custom list row..

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/RootView"        
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
```

now in your adapter ::

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewbyid(R.id.RootView);

linearLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {                 
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getAction()!=MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                    imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pressed_state);
                }else
                    btnArrow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal_stat);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

It works for me...
hope this help..